# Can't get result from parsing XML in SQL Server 2014 using sp_xml_preparedocument and OPENXML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following XML and I'm trying to select certain data from it using sp_xml_preparedocument and OPENXML, but I get no result:

```
DECLARE @hDoc AS INT
        ,@XML xml = '<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creator="MapSource 6.15.6" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
      <text>Garmin International</text>
    </link>
    <time>2013-06-25T13:37:18Z</time>
    <bounds maxlat="42.3806126" maxlon="27.7387079" minlat="42.3448138" minlon="27.7156218" />
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>ACTIVE LOG 033</name>
    <extensions>
      <gpxx:TrackExtension xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
        <gpxx:DisplayColor>White</gpxx:DisplayColor>
      </gpxx:TrackExtension>
    </extensions>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="42.3806126" lon="27.7234045">
        <time>2013-06-25T06:44:31Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <gpxx:TrackPointExtension xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
            <gpxx:Temperature>24.2592182</gpxx:Temperature>
            <gpxx:Depth>19.8200226</gpxx:Depth>
          </gpxx:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="42.3802007" lon="27.7237631">
        <time>2013-06-25T06:44:48Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <gpxx:TrackPointExtension xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
            <gpxx:Temperature>24.2816105</gpxx:Temperature>
            <gpxx:Depth>19.1851730</gpxx:Depth>
          </gpxx:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="42.3798285" lon="27.7240684">
        <time>2013-06-25T06:45:03Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <gpxx:TrackPointExtension xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
            <gpxx:Temperature>24.2928104</gpxx:Temperature>
            <gpxx:Depth>18.4135780</gpxx:Depth>
          </gpxx:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML,'<root xmlns:a="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"/>'

SELECT GPSName, GPSLat, GPSLon, GPSTime, GPSTemp, GPSDepth
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'gpx/trk/trkseg/trkpt/extensions/gpxx:TrackPointExtension')
WITH 
(
GPSName [varchar](100) '../../name'
,GPSLat decimal(18,7) '../../../../@lat'
,GPSLon decimal(18,7) '../../../../@lon'
,GPSTime datetime '../../../../time'
,GPSTemp decimal(18,7) '/gpxx:Temperature'
,GPSDepth decimal(18,7) '/gpxx:Depth'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Using above I get Null (zero rows). Can you help me understand what am I doing wrong? And how can I get the data correctly?

Just made a change in the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT GPSName, GPSLat, GPSLon, GPSTime, GPSTemp, GPSDepth
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'a:gpx/a:trk/a:trkseg/a:trkpt/a:extensions/gpxx:TrackPointExtension',1)
WITH 
(
GPSName [varchar](100) '../../name'
,GPSLat decimal(18,7) '../../../../@lat'
,GPSLon decimal(18,7) '../../../../@lon'
,GPSTime datetime '../../../../time'
,GPSTemp decimal(18,7) '/gpxx:Temperature'
,GPSDepth decimal(18,7) '/gpxx:Depth'
)
```

And now I get rows returned, but still only NULL values there:

```
GPSName                        GPSLat       GPSLon       GPSTime        GPSTemp        GPSDepth
------------------------------ ------------ ------------ -------------- -------------- ----------------
NULL                           NULL         NULL         NULL           NULL           NULL
NULL                           NULL         NULL         NULL           NULL           NULL
NULL                           NULL         NULL         NULL           NULL           NULL

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing more or less the same, thanks, but the XML is much more complicated (with namespaces, attributes and values at different depth) and obviously there is something more to apply to get the right result...

Answer (score 0):

The following Query will be helpful (For reference).

```
DECLARE @DocHandle INT,
        @Xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMl = N'<root><Salary>0.00</Salary></root>'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @Xml

SELECT CASE WHEN Salary <> 0 THEN Salary ELSE 10000 END AS Salary
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle , '/root')
WITH (Salary DECIMAL(18,3), 'Salary')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Salary
--------
10000
```